# How to resolve problem with mplleaflet.show?

Tags: python, geopandas

I'd like to learn draw maps & grid in python.
I found https://smarte-mobilitaet-blog.ftm.mw.tum.de/index.php/2019/09/17/coordinate-systems-projections-grids-and-visualization-in-python-practical-guide/
Step 5.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import mplleaflet
from math import ceil
from shapely.geometry import box
__author__ = "Lennart Adenaw"
__copyright__ = "Copyright 2019, Lennart Adenaw"
__credits__ = ["Lennart Adenaw"]
__license__ = "GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0 "
__version__ = "0.0.1"
__maintainer__ = "Lennart Adenaw"
__email__ = "adenaw@ftm.mw.tum.de"
###############################
#### OPTIONS                ####
###############################
# Define coordinate reference systems to use
METRIC_EPSG = {'init': 'epsg:31468'} # Gauss-Krueger Zone 4
WGS84_EPSG = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} # WGS 84 (GPS)
# Define bounding box in WGS84 (GPS) coordinates
MINX_MUC = 11.38
MAXX_MUC = 11.80
MINY_MUC = 48.00
MAXY_MUC = 48.25
# Define the number of rows and colums in the grid
N_ROWS = 25
N_COLS = 25
###############################
#### FUNCTIONS             ####
###############################
# Defines a function to create a grid inside a bounding box given by (minx, miny, maxx, maxy). Only Metric coordinates are allowed!

def createGrid(minx_grid, miny_grid, maxx_grid, maxy_grid, N_rows, N_cols):
    
    # Grid size
    grid_width = maxx_grid-minx_grid
    grid_height = maxy_grid-miny_grid
    
    # Cell size
    cell_width = grid_width/N_cols
    cell_height = grid_height/N_rows
    
    # Define grid origin as upper left grid corner
    origin_y = maxy_grid
    origin_x = minx_grid
    
    # Create grid cells
    grid_cells = []
    for i in range(N_rows): # For each row
        
        cell_origin_y = origin_y - i * cell_height # Calculate the current y coordinate
        
        for j in range(N_cols): # Create all cells in row
        
            cell_origin_x = origin_x + j * cell_width # Calculate the current x coordinate
            
            minx_cell = cell_origin_x
            miny_cell = cell_origin_y - cell_height
            maxx_cell = cell_origin_x + cell_width
            maxy_cell = cell_origin_y
            
            grid_cells.append(box(minx_cell, miny_cell, maxx_cell, maxy_cell)) # Store the new cell
            
    # Create a GeoDataFrame containing the grid
    grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=grid_cells)
    
    return grid, cell_width,  cell_height
    
###############################
#### SCRIPT                ####
###############################
    
# Bounding box as geopandas dataframe
muc = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[box(MINX_MUC, MINY_MUC, MAXX_MUC, MAXY_MUC)])
muc.crs = WGS84_EPSG
# Transformation to a metric crs
muc = muc.to_crs(METRIC_EPSG)
# Retrieving the transformed coordinates
muc_bounds = muc.total_bounds
# Create the grid using the munich bounding box
grid, cell_width_m, cell_height_m = createGrid(muc_bounds[0], muc_bounds[1], muc_bounds[2], muc_bounds[3], N_ROWS, N_COLS)
grid.crs = METRIC_EPSG
# Transform the grid back to the WGS84 system
grid = grid.to_crs(WGS84_EPSG)
# Plot the result using mplleaflet
ax = grid.plot(edgecolor='k')
mplleaflet.show(fig=ax.figure, crs=grid.crs, path='grid_map.html')
# Print the resulting sizes of the grid cells
print("Grid Statistics\nCell Width [m]: {}\nCell Height [m]: {}".format(cell_width_m, cell_height_m))
```

Unfortunately I have got an error: "type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not CRS".
I tried different combination with mplleaflet.show() but it didn't work.
Could You help me ?
Would You recommend another package to draw maps ?

Below I added Traceback:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [1] in <cell line: 84>
    mplleaflet.show(fig=ax.figure, crs=grid.crs, path='grid_map.html')

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\_display.py:180 in show
    save_html(fig, fileobj=f, **kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\_display.py:131 in save_html
    html = fig_to_html(fig, **kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\_display.py:82 in fig_to_html
    renderer = LeafletRenderer(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\leaflet_renderer.py:26 in __init__
    proj_in = pyproj.Proj(preserve_units=True, **crs)

TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not CRS
```

Comment: Please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors - it includes really important information for debugging

Comment: Thanks, I included.

Comment: related - https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet/issues/71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mplleaflet is a very old & unmaintained project. the last commit was in March 2018. frankly I'm surprised you're able to install it.

you should be able to plot a geodataframe on a leaflet map with [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html), e.g. in your case:

```py
grid.explore()
```

See the guide to [Interactive mapping](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/interactive_mapping.html) in geopandas for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks, I go to geopandas